# Creating a for loop that reduces long intergers to a number between 0 and 101

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, integer, long-integer

I am trying to create a for loop in Java that will take a long integer and reduce it to a value between 0-101. For example the number 89123 would be reduced to 89 and 10145 would be reduced to 101. I know that this can be done by continuously dividing the longer integer by 10 but I do not know how to write the loop so that it stops when the integer is somewhere in the range of 0-101. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It sounds kinda homework-y. Do you have any control on the number "101"?

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: This seems like a homework thing. Please post the code showing what have you tried till now. You won't get cooked answers here.

Comment: write down your idea in code, even if it is not working. If you try to solve it, we can help you with it. SO is not a platform to do your homework without effort on your side.

Comment: post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  of what you've done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public class Test {

    public static long getNumber(long input) {
       while(input > 101) {
           input = input /10;
       }
       return input;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

       System.out.println(getNumber(101111));
       System.out.println(getNumber(89123));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

     public static void main(String []args){

        long number;
        System.out.print("Enter number (to exit enter -1):");
        while((number = scanner.nextLong()) != -1){
            while(number > 101){
                number /= 10;
            }
            System.out.println(number);
            System.out.print("Enter number (to exit enter -1):");
        }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
 public int getNumber(long l){
  int lenght=(""+l).length();
  if(length<3)return (int)l;
  l/=(int)Math.Pow(10,length-3)
  if(new Long(l).equals(101)||new Long(l).equals(100))return (int)l;
  else return (int)(l/=10);
 }
```